# Can't get jQuery's .replaceWith() to work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Basically I am trying to have jQuery replace the button with the form and status div once clicked.

I am new to jQuery and hardly an advanced programmer so I am sure the solution will be relatively simple. On the other hand I am at my wits end with this issue and any help would be *greatly* appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Solution found. Interestingly enough it also only worked when I put it in a separate .js file and referenced it, *not* when I had it within  tags on the php page. Thanks again to everyone who responded!

---

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#repbutton").click(function() {
   $("#repbutton").replaceWith("<form id=\"reputation_form\" method=\"post\">
    Give positive reputation to <?=$reply_user['username']?> for their reply?
    Comment: <input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" /> 
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"uid\" value=\"<?=$reply_user['id']?>\">
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"rid\" value=\"<?=$replies_row['id']?>\">
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"urid\" value=\"<?=$user_row['id']?>\">
             <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Give Reputation\" />
</form>
<div id=\"status\">
        <p></p>
    </div>"); 

    });
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newlines aren't valid inside string literals unless you escape them with `\`.  Simply put, either compress the string to one line or add `\` to the end of each line:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#repbutton").click(function() {
   $("#repbutton").replaceWith("<form id=\"reputation_form\" method=\"post\">\
    Give positive reputation to <?=$reply_user['username']?> for their reply?\
    Comment: <input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" /> \
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"uid\" value=\"<?=$reply_user['id']?>\">\
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"rid\" value=\"<?=$replies_row['id']?>\">\
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"urid\" value=\"<?=$user_row['id']?>\">\
             <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Give Reputation\" />\
</form>\
<div id=\"status\">\
        <p></p>\
    </div>");

    });
});​
```

Working example -  **http://jsfiddle.net/rd4w9/**

Comment: Thanks so much - that seemed to fix the issues I was having. I eventually went for the "\" solution because if I have to come back to it that is much nicer to have to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just hide the button on click, and display the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `append()`, `prepend()` and `html()` functions for manipulating the DOM. Doing this your likely to confuse yourself and run into all sorts of problems.

You should be able to

- Hide the button
- Append the HTML for your form to the element the button is in

And then easily do the following once your done with the form

- Show the button again
- Remove the form

Answer (score 0):

You can't have return statements in your string like this in JavaScript, you need to declare it as a multi-line string using `\` on the end of each line, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#repbutton").click(function() {
   $("#repbutton").replaceWith("<form id=\"reputation_form\" method=\"post\"> \
    Give positive reputation to <?=$reply_user['username']?> for their reply? \
    Comment: <input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" /> \
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"uid\" value=\"<?=$reply_user['id']?>\"> \
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"rid\" value=\"<?=$replies_row['id']?>\"> \
             <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"urid\" value=\"<?=$user_row['id']?>\"> \
             <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Give Reputation\" /> \
</form> \
<div id=\"status\"> \
        <p></p> \
    </div>"); 

    });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/ASX2c/).

Comment: Looking at it you posted the same solution as the one that finally fixed it. Thanks!